# How do I get images w/ captions to remain in one row/on the same line?

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I want all three images to display in one row, with their respective caption below.

I have used `display: inline-block;` as I see most answers suggest, and the images are still wrapping to another line.

See below code.

Note that I do not have access to the external CSS file in this instance, so I need to address via inline code.

```
<div style="display: inline-block; padding-right: 10px;">
<figure><img title="Previous Winner" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/imgs/cms_pages/20160623_172407_resized.png"}}" alt="Previous Winner" width="300" /><figcaption>Michelle D. - Bakersfield, CA<br /> Fitbit&reg; Winner<br /> Spring 2016</figcaption></figure>
<figure><img title="Previous Winner" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/imgs/cms_pages/Check_winner__2.png"}}" alt="Previous Winner" width="300" /><figcaption>Gilberto M. - Hanford, CA<br /> $1,000 Cash Winner<br /> Summer 2016</figcaption></figure>
<figure><img title="Previous Winner" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/imgs/cms_pages/Eric_Boettcher.png"}}" alt="Previous Winner" width="300" /><figcaption>Eric B. - Brentwood, CA <br /> Baseball Getaway Winner<br /> Spring 2016</figcaption></figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

in your case the div is display inline block

give each img tag width:100%.

give each figure display inline block

fiddle example here :

[fiddle- click here](https://jsfiddle.net/r98o7fur/)

Comment: :). the post above also should work but "float" will get the element out from page flow. i add code example in fiddle.

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Answer (score 0):

To get this successfully, add the `display: inline-block;` on your figure elements. I also removed the margin as you will see on the fiddle.

You can see figure elements have the following default properties:

```
figure { 
    display: block;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
```

source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figure.asp

your HTML:

```
<div>
<figure style="display: inline-block; float: left; margin: 0;"><img title="Previous Winner" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/imgs/cms_pages/20160623_172407_resized.png"}}" alt="Previous Winner" width="300" /><figcaption>Michelle D. - Bakersfield, CA<br /> Fitbit&reg; Winner<br /> Spring 2016</figcaption></figure>
<figure style="display: inline-block; float: left; margin: 0"><img title="Previous Winner" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/imgs/cms_pages/Check_winner__2.png"}}" alt="Previous Winner" width="300" /><figcaption>Gilberto M. - Hanford, CA<br /> $1,000 Cash Winner<br /> Summer 2016</figcaption></figure>
<figure style="display: inline-block; float: left; margin: 0"><img title="Previous Winner" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/imgs/cms_pages/Eric_Boettcher.png"}}" alt="Previous Winner" width="300" /><figcaption>Eric B. - Brentwood, CA <br /> Baseball Getaway Winner<br /> Spring 2016</figcaption></figure>
</div>
```

You can remove it from your div.  See link to a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/john_h/w3uebtnb/